# Change active element in a list using react

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a list of elements created by using an array in react. On user click how can I make the clicked element active (by adding a CSS class) while making the other elements inactive (by removing the active class)?

My rendering of elements looks like this.

```
   {this.props.people.map(function(person, i){
        <div className='media' key={i} onClick={state.handleClick.bind(state,i,state.props)}>
          <item className="media-body">{person.name}</item>
        </div>
    }
```

When the user clicks on one of these elements an active class will be added to the clicked 'media' element making the clicked element 'media active' while removing the 'active' class from the previously clicked element??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeIndex: 0 };
  }

  handleClick(index, props) {
    // do something with props
    // ...    

    // now update activeIndex
    this.setState({ activeIndex: index });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.people.map(function(person, index) {
            const className = this.state.activeIndex === index ? 'media active' : 'media';  
            return (
              <div className={className} key={index} onClick={handleClick.bind(this, index, this.props)}>
                <item className="media-body">{person.name}</item>
              </div>
            );
          }, this)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your *handleClick* method you could store in the component's state the clicked person (looks like the collection is of people). Then set the *className* conditionally based on, say, the person's id.

You can set the className using something like:

```
className={this.state.clickedPersonId === i ? 'media media--clicked' : 'media'}
```

(NB This is using *i*, the index of the item in the *people* array; you may want to use something a little more explicit, like the person's real Id.)

Comment: I wouldn't do that since the index might get messed up if you remove or add array entries before the clicked entry.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I add the NB below. I was just trying to show the setting of the class, I don't know the properties of the person object.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clean code I personally would suggest you creating subcomponents to add functionality to mapped elements.

You could create a small subcomponent which simply returns the element which you want to add functionality to just like this :

```
...
this.state = {
active: false
}
...
return(
    <div className=`media ${this.state.active ? 'active' : ''` onClick={()=>{this.setState({active: true})}}>
      <item className="media-body">{this.props.name}</item>
    </div>
)
...
```

And in your map function you simply pass the contents as properties:

```
  {this.props.people.map(function(person, i){
    <SubComponent key={i} {...person} />
  }
```

That way you stay with clean code in the "root" component and can add complexity to your subcomponent.